# como acomodar texto en un documento con CSS usando display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, css3

estoy empezando a aprender CSS y para practicar me propuse hacer una web para un trabajo de la universidad el problema es que estoy queriendo acomodar un texto al lado de una imagen y no logro que quede bien, este me queda abajo de la misma. ya probé con display inline-block y le puse un width: 30%

adjunto el codigo y una captura de pantalla de como me queda.

CSS

```
.primer-parrafo{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div><p class="primer-parafo">Klarens Malluta es un artista Albano autodidacta que se 
    caracteriza por tener un estilo psicodelico y disruptivo. <br>
    gran parte de su trabajo se ve influenciado por internet dado que segun sus propias palabras 
   "El internet es lo mejor que le paso al ser humano nos permite acceder a todo tipo de 
    informacion y captar influencias de los lugares mas remoto, mi trabajo se ve potenciado y por 
    eso <br>
    siento que debo agradecerle al internet o al que sea que lo haya inventado por darme la 
    oportunidad de ser un artista hoy en dia" </p></div>
```

[image: Klarens Malluta]

Comment: la etiqueta img la ¿estás colocando justo a lado del párrafo o esta quedando dentro de otra etiqueta?

Comment: Hola, la etiqueta la estoy poniendo arriba del parrafo

<div class="imagen"><img src="img/birds.jpg" alt="birds" width="400px" height="500px" ></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La imagen queda por encima del texto en razón de que la colocaste dentro de un div el cual es un [elemento de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) y ocupará como notas todo el ancho disponible enviando al div del texto hacia abajo.

Entonces para lograr que el texto quede justo a la derecha de la imagen puedes emplear esta **opción**:

```
<style>
  .caja {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
  }
</style>

<div class="caja">
  <div class="caja-imagen">
    aqui iría la imagen
  </div>
  <div class="caja-texto">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut sapiente, amet tempore fugiat quos eligendi necessitatibus illum quisquam nulla similique ipsam nesciunt voluptatem incidunt praesentium saepe, modi in minus doloremque.
  </div>
</div>
```

Donde como notas a través de [*CSS Grid*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) le indicamos al contenedor que divida a sus elementos internos en 2 columnas de igual ancho.

Ahora si decides continuar con el uso de *inline-block* entonces debes aplicarlo a ambos div (es decir tanto al que contiene al imagen como al que contiene el párrafo), además creo que deberás definir un width para ambos elementos.

No debes colocarlo a la clase del párrafo por que de ese modo solo *afectarás* su contenido, es decir el texto pero seguirás sin lograr la distribución horizontal que pretendes.

Comment: buenisimo, con esto me funciono mil gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza mejor display flex, flex alinea los hijos del contenedor, en el eje del block (horizontal) por defecto a menos que lo cambies con flex direction. Y listo tienes alineados los elementos en linea.

```html
    <style>
        .content{
            display:flex
         }
         .content p{  
            width: 30%;
         }

    </style>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/" alt=""> 
        <p class="primer-parafo">
            Klarens Malluta es un artista Albano autodidacta que se 
            caracteriza por tener un estilo psicodelico y disruptivo. 
            <br>
            gran parte de su trabajo se ve influenciado por internet 
            dado que segun sus propias palabras.  "El internet es lo 
            mejor que le paso al ser humano nos permite acceder a 
            todo tipo de  informacion y captar influencias de los 
            lugares mas remoto, mi trabajo se ve potenciado y por  
            eso <br>
            siento que debo agradecerle al internet o al que sea que 
            lo haya inventado por darme la oportunidad de ser un artista hoy en dia" 
        </p>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/scarabax/pen/xxdymxB

Comment: No, lo acabo de probar y sigue igual